# Julia CartesianIndex to integer LinearIndex conversion

Tags: indexing, julia

To convert a CartesianIndex, such as `CartesianIndex(1,2)` to a LinearIndex, [I can use the LinearIndeces function](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-convert-cartesianindex-n-values-to-int64/15074/4):

```
julia> a = rand(2,2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.57097   0.0647051
 0.767868  0.531104

julia> I = LinearIndices(a)
2×2 LinearIndices{2,Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}}:
 1  3
 2  4

julia> I[CartesianIndex(1,2)]
3
```

However, how do I get the LinearIndex integer `3` for `CartesianIndex(1,2)` without constructing the instance of the array `a`? Assuming I know the ranges for the CartesianIndex, `1:2, 1:2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `LinearIndices` with a tuple of the axes (or even just a tuple of dimension sizes):

```
julia> LinearIndices((1:2,1:2))
2×2 LinearIndices{2,Tuple{UnitRange{Int64},UnitRange{Int64}}}:
 1  3
 2  4

julia> LinearIndices((1:2,1:2))[1,2]
3
```